# How to configure bridging

Tags: networking, virtualbox, bridge

I am trying to configure a bridged network in a CentOS machine created with virtual box. I already did the same on two ubuntu 12.04 machines, and this is how the /etc/network/interfaces file looks like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

This way on the ubuntu machine, the IP address 192.168.0.x is associated with the br0 interface:

[image]

Instead on the CentOS machine that IP address is still associated with the eth0 interface:

[image]

This makes me think that I'm still missing something in the network configuration. But the problem is that there isn't such file as /etc/network/interface in CentOS, instead there is /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0, but the syntax is totally different. Does anyone know how to do the same in CentOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change following configuration to your needs.

```
vim /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0
DEVICE=br0
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=static
DNS1=192.168.0.1
GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
IPADDR=192.168.0.100
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ONBOOT=yes
SEARCH=”example.com”
```

Modify eth0 configuration:

```
vim /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=00:1e:90:f3:f0:02
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
IPV6INIT=no
USERCTL=no
BRIDGE=br0
```

Comment: Just one question: why the netmask is 255.255.255.0? I though it was 255.255.0.0. This is what I read in RFC 1918: 192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)

Comment: you can put the mask what ever you want it's just an example in my Virtual network